# Как сделать, чтобы цикл отрабатывал ( цвет и id задавался)?

Tags: javascript

при задании атрибута пишет
title.attr is not a function

```js
let titles = Array.from($('a'));
(let title of titles) {
    title.css("color", "red");
    //title.attr('id', ' Новое значение' );
   
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<a href="title title 1">title title 1</a>
<a href="title title 2">title title 2</a>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Пропущено `for` — вместо `(let title of titles) {` нужно `for (let title of titles) {`

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, пропущено, но не решает проблему

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, https://jsfiddle.net/4nbz0pyj/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let titles = Array.from($('a'));
for(let title of titles) {
    $(title).css("color", "red");
     $(title).attr('id', ' Новое значение' );
   
}
```

Наверно стоит дополнительно пояснить, что когда вылезает ошибка is not a function, это значит, что нет такого метода у объекта, к которому вы обращаетесь, что должно наводить на определенные мысли.

Comment: спасибо огромное